# How to iterate a list of superclass and accessing subclass properties?

Tags: java, oop, inheritance

Editing my question because I realized better what I want:

Say we have `List<A>` with bunch of instances of classes extending A each with its own unique properties.

Like in this example:

1. class A has field int x, getter and setter.
2. class B extends A, and also has field int y with its getter and setter.
3. class C extends A, and also has field int z with its getter and setter.

I don't want to use downcasting and `instanceof` when iterating the list.

I read this post which was interesting:
https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/245263/how-to-avoid-downcasting

What is the right approach?

Thanks

Comment: `B b = new B()`.

Comment: If you need y, just do B b = new B() in the first place.

Comment: Also it does make sense for a subclass to have more fields than its super class. Every time you write your own class with a field you’re doing that, because it extends Object which does not have that field.

Comment: Right but A b is better practice. that's why I ask if it makes sense

Comment: It’s better practice for interfaces, e.g. List<String> x = new ArrayList<>() but for classes, I don’t think it is.

Comment: It's better practice if all you care about, in the rest of the code, is that the variable refers to an A. It's not the case here. You very rarely do `Object o = "hello"`, right? Because you want a variable of type String, not a variable of type Object.

Comment: and if its List<A> with bunch of instances of classes extending A each with its own unique properties, then use `instanceof` every time I want to use one of these properties?

Comment: No. Use a polymorphic method of each object, or an adapter, or the visitor pattern.

Comment: thanks @jb-nizet, this was actually what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

In most cases, you should be doing `B b = new B()` instead of `A b = new B()`. If you must use a field of type `A`, then downcasting is your best bet. Keep in mind, though, that it shouldn't happen very often.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I changed my question a bit.

Comment: This answer is wrong for the general case. The main rule is to code to the interface, to the abstraction, not to the concrete. Avoid coding to the concrete unless absolutely necessary. There are whole design patterns created to avoid doing this, such as the Visitor Pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it does makes sense for a sub-class to have more fields than it's super.

If you find yourself having to downcast, then it likely means that you should instantiate the variable with the static class that you are down-casting to, in this case, do `B b = new B()` instead of `A b = new B()`.
When you use `A b = new B()`, it means the context/function in which you want to use the variable expects an object of type `A` (i.e. expects to use functions that are declared in `A`), therefore if you are down-casting to `B`, you may need to review your design and ask yourself the data type that you want to work with in that context/function.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I changed my question a bit.